# Pass Variable from python (flask) to HTML in render template?

Tags: python, html, parsing, variables, flask

The web server works (python flask) but when I go to the website, where the value of animal should be (dog) it shows the variable name animal. (There is more to the code but this is the most simplistic version which is the same concept.

Let's say I have these lines of code in my python script running python flask.

```
animal = dog
return render_template('index.html', value=animal)
```

and in my HTML

```
<h3>I like the animal: {{ value }}<h3>
```

but rather than displaying 'dog' it displays the variable name 'animal'. So how would I go about displaying the Python variable to HTML? Thank you

Comment: I'd need to see some more code. I believe that should work, unless dog == 'animal'

Comment: No for some reason it doesn't work it just displays 'animal' rather than 'dog'

Comment: I'd need to see where `dog` is defined. As you're showing it, `dog` is another variable. Unless you meant to type `animal = 'dog'`. If you edit your code with the whole view it would be easier to tell you. Because as it is, this is correct.

Comment: Is there a way I can get this in `url_for` parameter? with `{{ value }}`

Comment: A good way to apply this method is to create an input and use the value in the value attribute, as in the example. <input type="hidden" value="{{ value }}" id="animal">

Answer (score 65):

Shouldn't it be `animal = 'dog'`? If 'dog' is the value you want to see printed after "I like the animal:", this is what you need to do:

```
animal = 'dog'
return render_template('index.html', value=animal)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can get this in `url_for` parameter? with `{{ value }}`

Comment: @Dev yes going along with this example, use `{{ url_for('static', filename=value) }}` assuming that value is set to your intended url destination

Answer (score 0):

As you have to pass a value using a variable you have to define it as a string like:
`animal = 'dog'`
then pass it to the html template:
`return render_template('index.html', value=animal)`

Now, you should see the passed value in the HTML.

Comment: Is there a way I can get this in `url_for` parameter? with `{{ value }}`

Answer (score 0):

To pass one variable, simply provide it as a keyword argument to the render_template function:

```
render_template("index.html", name='test')
```

In the template, you can access the variable directly:

```
<h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
```

To pass multiple variables, create a dictionary containing the variables and provide it as keyword arguments:

```
context = {
    'name': name,
    'age': age
}

render_template("index.html", **context)
```

In the template, you can access the variables directly:

```
<h1>Hello, {{ name }}!</h1>
<p>You are {{ age }} years old.</p>
```