# How to POST json file contents as application/json from flask template?

Tags: python, html, json, flask

I have a flask form below which uploads JSON file to another endpoint.
However, the form I have so far, is encoded as multipart/form-data.

I do not think that there is an application/json encoding for forms?

How do I have the form POST to the endpoint the contents of the JSON file?

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}    
                               
{% block title %}Upload{% endblock %}

{% block body %}               
      <form action = "/upload" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>        
      </form>                  
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can't you just do it with javascript? like ajax call?

Comment: Might have to...cheers, investigating Ajax call ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML forms do not support application/json POST. But you can use Ajax call with or without a button click event. Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'THE URL YOU WANT TO POST TO',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        name: "anon_dcs3spp"
    }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
});
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciated! How do I read the JSON from contained in the file in the Ajax code?

Comment: if you are reading the json from a file, you have to read it separately in your application. Use `json.load` to load the file content to a variable. then pass that variable to your template.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149420/pass-variable-from-python-flask-to-html-in-render-template/45151521) is how to pass variable to your template

Comment: Ok, thanks. I need to have the flask template rendered so that the file is selected for upload on client side and when click upload it POSTS to a different endpoint with json payload containing the json file contents. Will accept answer since it looks like Ajax is the way forward on client side. I just need to figure how to get it to read the file selected in the form client side and send it...

Comment: Oh, so you want the file to be uploaded and its content (which is json) read on another route?  you can just use html form to upload and post the file, and then receive the file content  and store it in a variable. You may not need the ajax call.

Comment: why do you want to post a form in json format? you can just upload the file from one side and read it and store the json content in a variable on the other side.