# Get data from database into Flask template table

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Dears,

I am new to Flask and HTML. I created a python app that is controlled by a SQL Server database (data and settings)

I needed an admin interface, so I used the below template and redesigned the pages.
https://github.com/app-generator/flask-argon-dashboard

I just need to query database from this Flask app and put the data into a table in this template. I searched a lot with no hope.

Comment: Maybe this can help.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6597/flask-python-reporting-for-sql-server/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass Variable from python (flask) to HTML in render template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149420/pass-variable-from-python-flask-to-html-in-render-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using pyodbc to query data, and edit /app/home/routes.py like the below:

def myfunction

And then:
return render_template("home/" + template, segment=segment, data=myfunction())

and on the HTML files, but {% for roww in data %} and {% endfor %} into

Comment: For the future, you should include more information about what you're having trouble with along with additional context.  No one can see your code or your folder structure so it could be hard for someone to help.  It also doesn't look like you spent a lot of time search online for answers, as you can find how to do this in a lot of posts and other online resources.